# Java Spring JPA Repository between date query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hello I have entity and have createdAt filed specified like this:

```
@JsonIgnore
@Column(name = "created_at")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
protected Date createdAt;
```

Every entity includes this field. Now I have complicated SQL query which calculates profit between dates. Query looks like this:

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN t.outcome = true THEN - t.amount ELSE t.amount END) as income " +
            "FROM Transaction t " +
            "WHERE t.property = :property " +
            "AND t.createdAt BETWEEN :dateFrom AND :dateTo")
    Double getPropertyProfitBetweenDates(@Param("property")Property property, @Param("dateFrom")Date dateFrom, @Param("dateTo")Date dateTo);
```

The function that parses dates as I want looks like this:

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
start.add(Calendar.MONTH, -i);
start.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
start.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
start.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
start.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
start.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

Calendar end;
end = (Calendar) start.clone();
end.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
end.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);

Date dateFrom = start.getTime();
Date dateTo = end.getTime();
```

When I try to access data via repository I call method like this:

```
transactionService.getPropertyProfitBetweenDates(property, dateFrom, dateTo)
```

Every time I receive null, but when I mannualy run query in mysql workbench I get correct records. Could you please help me solving this problem out?

Comment: if you receive NULL, then you should start with debugging and find out why

Comment: log the time that you pass to the query and enable the query logging and check which values are passed and what is the real query run against the database

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem using `java.sql.Date`